# Events and metadata on Google Drive documents

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I would like to add annotated text to a document. It's important to keep track of this text as changing it will cause other parts of the document to change. A quick example would be I want to plan a meal with several different recipes. I would like to keep a running list of ingredients at the bottom, but also write out how to prepare, cook, and present the meal. It would have a format something like:

> ## Cooking Plan #12
>
> [text]
>
> #### Recipe # 1 (has embedded ingredient list in meta data)
>
> [steps]
>
> #### Recipe # 2 (has embedded ingredient list in meta data)
>
> [steps]
>
> ..etc
>
> ### Ingredients Needed
>
> [list all ingredients required from all recipes]

A user would drop recipes into the document, be able to move them around, edit them, and write text surrounding it. A recipe would keep a list of it's ingredients, keeping updated with an ingredients page at the end that sums up what you'll need to purchase for the meal. When a recipe is added or removed, the ingredient list needs to be updated.

Is it possible to add meta data and events to a document in this fashion?

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently available, sorry. But adding arbitrary metadata is coming soon (that's all I can say about it). I'm not sure if that covers your case, but it should work.

Could you describe your document format a bit better?